# Starburst Fruit Chews kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, hechsher-certification

Are Starburst Fruit Chews kosher? This website below clearly has an OU on the right side. However, Gelatin appears on the ingredient list, and the oukosher.org website doesn't have any reference to Starburst, as far as I can tell.

https://www.marsfoodservices.com/products-brands/candy/starburst.aspx

Comment: welcome back :)

Comment: Thanks. Returning bc it's a matter of vital importance, of course.

Comment: The only thing I found on OU is an old alert related to the variety pack. See https://oukosher.org/kosher-alerts/skittles-starburst-variety-pack/. Best bet is to call OU directly. If you get an answer, please post.

Comment: Another point to consider is that the OU only appears next to one of the products. This may mean that the others are not kosher. Do you see an OU on the actual product in the store?

Comment: I received a package of individually wrapped candies.  No OU on the individual wrappers.

Comment: How frustrating. Im Muslim and rely on the Kosher symbols to help me buy/eat food. Ive been eating and passing out Starburst to little kids bc of the OU symbol only to find out it was false!

Comment: I don't see an OU on the pictures of the two Starburst products currently on that web site.

Answer (score 8):

Although the website has an OU printed there, if you [click in](https://www.marsfoodservices.com/products-brands/candy/starburst.aspx?upc=01151&mfgID=000323&pid=72&ptbId=308) to the nutritional information it says that it is not Kosher.

In addition, [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111031185812AA2tfwp) is a reproduction of an e-mail claimed to be from the company saying that the gelatin in the product is beef.  It is not economically feasible to use Kosher beef to make commercial gelatin, and the OU [does not regard](https://oukosher.org/blog/industrial-kosher/the-fascinating-story-of-kosher-gelatin-or-how-a-product-from-beef-can-be-used-in-dairy-delicacies/) gelatin derived from non-Kosher animals as Kosher.

So it would seem that the reasonable conclusion is that it is not Kosher according to the OU, and the OU should be contacted about the misplacement of their symbol on the website you linked.

Comment: Thanks.  Agreed - that will probably be the conclusion.  I emailed OUkosher yesterday, so I'll be sure to post the reply.

Comment: @ArghMo Any update?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the reply I received from the OU.  The Webbe Rebee didn't say anything about the OU appearing on the Starburst website.

*Thank you for contacting the OU.

We do not currently certify any Starburst candy.

Please do not hesitate to contact us again should you have any further questions.

Sincerely,

The Web(be) Rebbe
Orthodox Union Kashruth Division*

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I sent the following note to Mars and will post here if I get a reply: *Your product page for Starburst Fruit Chews (https://www.marsfoodservices.com/products-brands/candy/starburst.aspx) displays the "O-U" symbol of the Orthodox Union with rollover text of "Kosher," but someone who contacted the Orthodox Union (http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56694/2) learned that "We do not currently certify any Starburst candy." As such, the use of this symbol on the product page probably constitutes false advertising. I recommend that you remove it.*

Comment: @IsaacMoses Looks like it was removed?

Comment: @DoubleAA indeed, it has. I didn't get any other response from them, but I'm glad of this outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to Wrigley's which actually makes Starburst and consumer info lady said "it's not kosher but every thing in it is kosher"

I laughed inside

My next obvious question was what does she know about the gelatin?

Her answer was "it's beef derived "

So not kosher but actully treif big time

Comment: Why is beef derived gelatin "treif big time"?

Answer (score -1):

Beef derived gelatin is still beef, so I think the gelatin would have to be derived from kosher beef, which is not likely what Starburst would pay for.

Comment: Plus they'd have to mark it "fleishig" so people can wait 6 hours after eating a fruit chew.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm pretty sure the OU regards beef derived gelatin as pareve. They require the material to be Kosher, but the resultant product they do not regard as fleishig.

Comment: @Yishai Oh sure, but I'm just speaking accd to the OP's logic. Other people think it's not only pareve but kosher even from non-kosher beef. The OP though can't fathom its changing halakhic status at all.